# Css background image : net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: html, css

i am using background image  for bottom of the header like  this

```
header {
 background:url(../img/header_bg.png) #ea6225 no-repeat;   
 background-size: 100% auto;
 background-position:left bottom; 
}
```

My images are in a folder like this `Web/img/header_bg.png`    and  css   `Web/css/style.css`

now when i see in browser this image is being loaded but in console it shows error  like this

> file:///C:/Users/name/Desktop/Web/img/header_bg.png 
>   net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

same this is happening with  ttf fonts used in my project . Will someone help me whats wrong with it ?

Comment: Are you sure the file name and extension is correct..?

Comment: Yes as i mentioned it is displayed  in web page but console gives error

Comment: Check if you have same file

Comment: i hate to say it, but the only way it would happen is if the mentioned image doesnt exist. maybe, just a small chance, that your picture whas named something else at first, and then you tried to rename your file to "header_bg.png"?

Comment: @Banana - he says it renders in the browser, so I'd assume it must exist.  That suggests to me that it is a console issue.  My *guess* (and it is a guess) would be something to do with the files being hosted off-line.

Comment: Which browser are you using?
And have you tried the same with other browsers? Does the console error appear in them too?

Comment: it still doesn't contradict my statement, this issue only occurs when the mentioned file does not exist. it is possible that the image he sees is *not* the image that fails to load, he might be calling the image again from a different place. i did encounter a similar issue once though, when navigating through pages which are located in **different folder tree level**, file is being called with "../" when in fact the calling page is located in "../../" maybe the error OP receives was left in the console from a different page ?

Answer (score 3):

According to W3, partial URLs are interpreted relative to the source of the style sheet, not relative to the document. You should set the URL accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 background:url(../../img/header_bg.png) #ea6225 no-repeat;
```

Comment: On what basis have you assumed that the png file is two folders above the current page?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add "" like this ("../../img/header_bg.png")

Comment: That's not correct. Quotes are [optional](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#value-def-uri)

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind,

```
<img src="Lanka.jpg">       <!-- Lanka.jpg is in the current folder -->
<img src="Asia/Lanka.jpg">  <!-- Lanka.jpg is in the Asia folder -->
<img src="/Asia/Lanka.jpg"> <!-- Asia folder is in root folder -->
<img src="../Lanka.jpg">    <!-- Lanka.jpg is in one folder up from current folder-->
```

Answer (score 0):

well...
no clue why is it so, but when I've tried to enter

```
file:///C:/Users/admin/Downloads/new%20project/images/header/background.png
```

everythings started to work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).